# What's the difference between total function and count function?

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel

I found out that the functions count and total on the elementCriteriaModel show different results:

The following examples gave different results. `paginate.total` was the same as `total`, but not correct. Only count showed me the correct answer.

```
{% paginate craft.entries(filterParams).section('object').order('title asc').limit(resultsLimit) as results %}

Total results:{{ paginate.total }}

{% set total =  craft.entries(filterParams).section('object').order('title asc').total() %}
{% set count =  craft.entries(filterParams).section('object').order('title asc').count() %}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.count` will return the total results for a particular paginated page (in your case, it should be the same as the `resultsLimit` variable).

`.total` will return the number of results in the entire results object regardless of pagination.